# Why LIMIT и OFFSET (OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH FIRST ... ROW only) functions in PostgreSQL are not working?

Tags: sql, postgresql, fetch, limit, offset

I am trying to use LIMIT and OFFSET functions or OFFSET ... ROWS
FETCH FIRST ... ROW only. PostgreSQL gives me the wrong number of rows in result.

```
select user_id, max(order_ts) as lastorder
from production.orders
group by user_id 
order by lastorder desc, user_id desc
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 20 ROW only
```

or

```
select user_id, max(order_ts) as lastorder
from production.orders
group by user_id 
order by lastorder desc, user_id desc
OFFSET 10 
limit 20
```

Still gives me 20 rows (should be 10: from 10th row to 20th - is 10).

How is this? Any help, please?

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data and expected output?

Comment: move offset after limit

Comment: Limit 20 gives a maximum of 20 rows, not 10. Offset 10 tells the database how many records to skip before returning the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIMIT 20` tells server to return not more than 20 records. `FETCH FIRST 20 ONLY` is absolutely the same. The query might return 20 rows or less depending on the data and query conditions. If you are trying to get rows from 11th to 20th then you need to specify `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`.

See the paragraph *LIMIT Clause* in the documentation for details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT